# Excel Formula - Referencing cells on a closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I have an Excel formula that gets inserted into a cell through VBA code when a user presses a button.

```
=SUM(OFFSET(INDEX('" & filePath & "[" & workbookName & ".xlsx]" & sheetName & "'!D$4:XFD$500,,MATCH(C" & i ",'" & filePath & "[" & workbookName & ".xlsx]" & sheetName & "'!D$2:XFD$2,0)),,1))
```

So the problem with this is that for some reason Excel does not like me using OFFSET for a workbook that is closed, and is returning #VALUE. This does work if I take away the OFFSET, but it doesnt grab the column I need.

I cannot simply refer to the column because the cell I am finding a MATCH for is merged across two columns, and I need to reference the right-most column, hence the OFFSET.

Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: You can simply add 1 to the result of MATCH.

Comment: @BigBen so simple! Can't believe I didnt think of that. Amazing, thank you!